# Utils class dependency injection - kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have two different @Service classes that use the same methods.
I have extracted those methods in a separate class, that both will reference. To be able to access those methods, I added them to the companion object of the class, but the issue is that they use external services in their implementation, which I cannot wire in a companion object or pass it and access it there.

```
  class CommonMethods {

    companion object {
      fun firstValidationField(input: User) {
        // logic
        input.timezone = userRepository.getTimezone(input.userId)
        return input
     }
       etc
    }
   }
```

What is the best way to inject userRepository to this class so I can access it and have the common methods work for both external service classes?

I had these methods in the service class, so autowiring repositories there wasn't an issue. But extracting them as they are common, not sure how to approach this.
I use @Autowired to inject it

Answer (score 0):

If `firstValidationField()` is really so simple as you wrote in the question, you can inject the `userRepository` in your both services, and `userRepo.getTimeZone(..)` that's it.

However, if the method impl. is more complex than that, or there are other commonly used methods, I would suggest wrapping those methods in an additional @service, say UserService, and inject the UserService into your other @services.

Usually, Util classes are not designed to be instantiated, it contains mainly static method calls. IMO, "Injecting" objects to a Util class isn't the right direction to go.